# Can i use queryselector in angular 9 application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

QuerySelector is part of typescript or javascript. Can I use this in my angular application Which one needs to use instead of QuerySelector in angular application. Why I am asking, Suppose generating dynamic HTML on that condition I want to handle some event on the dynamically generated HTML.
On that condition, querySelector is very easy. But some people are telling like do not to use quesrySelector that is not good practice. So, How to handle these issue?

```
document.querySelector(".myclass");
document.querySelector("ul").querySelectorAll('li');
```

Comment: use @ViewChild instead of querySelector

Comment: Because Angular manages the DOM. You'll eventually end up pointing to elements that don't exist anymore because of how often Angular adds/removes them.

Comment: Yes you can do it, but it is not the recommend way

Answer (score 0):

In order to dynamically render content you can use structural directive like `*ngIf`

```
<div>
    <p *ngIf="displayElement; else showThis">Content</p>
    <ng-template #showThis>      
        else content
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

`querySelector` it's not a good practice in Angular.
Instead of using querySelector or similar from there, a declarative way can be used instead to access elements in the view directly:

```
<input #myname> // html

@ViewChild('myname') input; // add this in ClassComponent

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.input.nativeElement.value); // Input will be available in this lifecycle
}
```

Comment: How we can use this for dynamically generated HTML